# How to transfer project from one group to a user in gitlab CE 9?

Tags: gitlab

I want to transfer a project from a group to another user. For e.g from https://gitlab.local/groupname/projectname to https://gitlab.local/userA/projectname

How can I achieve this? I have gitadmin permissions.

Answer (score 70):

Go to

**Settings** ▶ **General** ▶ **Advanced** ▶ **Transfer project**
▶ **Select a new namespace**

[image]

Comment: This explains how to transfer a project from a group to another group, but not from a group to a user namespace.

Answer (score 8):

Contrary the other answer, on this way you can move only a project to another namespace where you are an owner. Being a gitlab admin is not enough for that; you need to have

1. "owner" permission to the the project.
2. "owner" permission to the target namespace.

This is why you can see only your own personal namespace in the list of the possible targets in the **Settings ⇒ General ⇒ Advanced ⇒ Transfer Project** option.

What I did to solve the problem:

1. I gave "owner" permission for "userA" on the project.
2. Then, I impersonated "userA" ("Impresonate" button in the top right corner on the user admin page, which is https://your.gitlab.host/admin/users/userA ).
3. Then, I went to the project profile page
4. And then, **Settings ⇒ General ⇒ Advanced ⇒ Transfer**, as "userA", has already displayed the personal namespace of "userA" as one of the possible targets.

This is for the latest stable Gitlab (12.9.1).

Making yourself an owner of the personal namespace of "userA" might also work, however I did not find any way to manipulate permissions on personal namespaces.