# Transfer gitlab repo to a different group

Tags: gitlab

In the gitlab documentation, it reads

> Transferring an existing project into a group
>
> You can transfer an existing project into a group you own from the project settings page. 
>      First scroll down to the 'Dangerous settings' and click 'Show them to me'. 
>      Now you can pick any of the groups you manage as the new namespace for the group.

But I cannot even manage to find the settings page.
In the docs there is the following figure:

[image]

However, my sidebar looks as follows:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437030/how-to-transfer-project-from-one-group-to-a-user-in-gitlab-ce-9

Solution is here you are reffering to 2014 solution of gitlab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer project from one group to a user in gitlab CE 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437030/how-to-transfer-project-from-one-group-to-a-user-in-gitlab-ce-9)

Comment: It does not. I guess it is most likely a permissions issue ?

Comment: definitely a permissions issue. I recommend asking your administrator or group owner.